# Elvis Operator vs Non-Null Assertion: Diff Between These Statements?

Tags: nullpointerexception, kotlin, type-safety, kotlin-null-safety

Trying to understand null safety in Kotlin: both of these following statements seem to work fine and be interchangeable in my program:

```
var y1: Double = 0.0
    get() = when(hasParent) {
        true -> parent!!.y1
        else -> field
    }
```

and

```
var y1: Double = 0.0
    get() = parent?.y1!!
```

(`hasParent` is simply a getter to see if `parent` is null or not)

Are these two semantically the same or are they actually different expressions that mean different things? And if they mean the same thing semantically, is the first ever preferred over the second for any reason?

Comment: The second form is different from the first, and isn't correct. You'd get `NullPointerException` if `parent` is null. `parent?.y1 ?: field` is equivalent to the first form.

Comment: Would you move that to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you don't need `hasParent`. The form which is applicable is this:\

```
var y1: Double = 0.0
    get() = parent?.y1 ?: field
```

The problem with your second getter is that it will try to return the `parent.y1` no matter what and it will throw a `NullPointerException` if it is not there.

If you use IDEA you'll get warnings for these kinds of problems so they are an easy fix, but you need to be aware of the so called platform types which come from Java code:

```
val queue: Queue<String> = LinkedList()
queue.peek().toInt()
```

Here the compiler won't complain for `.toInt()` although it is possible to get a null from the `Queue`. I've written about this [here](http://the-cogitator.com/2017/10/02/kotlin-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them.html#handling-nulls-from-the-jdk).

Answer (score 1):

Note that jingx's and Adam Arold's answer is good for the current situation, but it wouldn't be equivalent to your first snippet if the type of `y1` was nullable: if `parent` is not null, but `parent.y1` is, then your code gives `null` and `parent?.y1 ?: field` gives `field`.

I'd say the actual preferred form if you need the first behavior is

```
if (parent != null) parent.y1 else field // if parent is val without a custom getter
parent.let { if (it != null) it.y1 else field } // otherwise
```

Using `hasParent` hides from the compiler that you actually checked for null and don't need `!!`.